# Protection 'from' germs vs Protection 'against' germs?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the two is grammatically correct?

Also, would the usage change if I change 'protection' to 'protects'?

Comment: They're both grammatically correct.  And both mean about the same thing, in most contexts, though "from" is probably a hair more idiomatic.  But it really depends on context.

Comment: If I was being really picky, I’d say that protecting ***from*** something means that the thing is prevented from getting to you, while protecting ***against*** something means that while the thing can get to you, it is prevented from harming you.

Comment: The more I think about it the more counter examples I come up with though.

Answer (score 3):

There's no remarkable difference between **protect from** and **protect against**. As for me, I'd use **protect from** as it is more commonly used and sounds better. Nevertheless, this is a personal preference rather than a deliberate choice.

Answer (score -1):

Protection from new germs in current environment => use newest soap in market

Protection against existing germs in environment => your soap already provides

I think both are correct. Give some context and it becomes apparent.

Edit: The usage won't change with "protects" instead of "protection".